# Investigate the 8 fields arround every field in two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

How to check the 8 neighbours of the field? I mean some fields have just 3 neighbours, because they are on the border of the array. 
thanks for help

Comment: The answer lies in the task you're trying to perform, tell us about it)

Comment: I'm guessing you do a lot of -1,0,+1 in two directions, and check the limits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so you need to take account of that by checking for the row and column values being 0 or the height/width. If you're just adding up values, you may find it easiest to have a method which just returns the value in the array, or 0 if you're asking for a value out of range:

```
int GetValue(int[,] array, int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 ||
        x >= array.GetLength(0) || y >= array.GetLength(1))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return array[x, y];
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        int total = GetValue(array, x - 1, y - 1)
                  + GetValue(array, x, y - 1)
                  + GetValue(array, x + 1, y - 1)
                  + GetValue(array, x - 1, y)
                  + GetValue(array, x + 1, y)
                  + GetValue(array, x - 1, y + 1)
                  + GetValue(array, x, y + 1)
                  + GetValue(array, x + 1, y + 1);
        // Do something with the total
    }
}
```

Note that all the calls to `GetLength` are pretty inefficient here. There are alternatives which would be more efficient, but a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be written shorter, but it's easy to understand:

```
int[,] theArray = new int[4,4]{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
bool above = true;
bool below = true;
bool left = true;
bool right = true;
for (int i = 0; i < theArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < theArray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        above = true; below = true; left = true; right = true;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            above = false;
        }
        if (i == theArray.GetLength(0) - 1)
        {
            below = false;
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            left = false;
        }
        if (j == theArray.GetLength(1) - 1)
        {
            right = false;
        }
        if (above)
        {
            if (left)
            {
                CheckField(i - 1, j - 1, theArray);
            }
            CheckField(i - 1, j, theArray);
            if (right)
            {
                 CheckField(i - 1, j + 1, theArray);
            }
        }
        if (left)
        {
            CheckField(i, j - 1, theArray);
        }
        if (right)
        {
            CheckField(i, j + 1, theArray);
        }
        if (below)
        {
            if (left)
            {
                CheckField(i + 1, j - 1, theArray);
            }
            CheckField(i + 1, j, theArray);
            if (right)
            {
                CheckField(i + 1, j + 1, theArray);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void CheckField(int i, int j, int[,] theArray)
{
    // do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because i dont know what you want to do i have this Neighbour class here:

```
public class Neighbour
{

    public Neighbour(int x, int y, int value)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

and one function here:

```
public List<Neighbour> checkArrayField(int[,] array, int coord_x, int coord_y)
    {
        List<Neighbour> ret = new List<Neighbour>();

        for (int i = coord_x - 1; i < array.GetLength(0) && i <= coord_x+1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = coord_y - 1;j < array.GetLength(1) && j <= coord_y+1; j++)
            {
                if(( i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i != coord_x | j != coord_y) ) //Not the Element in the Middle or negative indices
                {
                    ret.Add(new Neighbour(i, j, array[i, j]));
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

for testing:

```
int[,] array = new int[4, 4] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
                               { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 
                               { 9,10,11,12 }, 
                               {13,14,15,16 } };

        List<Neighbour> Neighbours = checkArrayField(array, 0, 0);
```

then you have a List with Neighbours (coords and value) and can do whatever you want to do with them
hope this helps